# Migrating from Silverlight 2 to 3

Tags: silverlight-3.0

We are considering porting a moderately complex Silverlight 2 app to Silverlight 3. Are there any potential pitfalls to be aware of? Have people had good experience doing this port?

I'm aware of the [MSDN guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645049%28VS.95%29.aspx) on porting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far our porting of a LOB application was successful. We used 3rd party controls where we had to wait until they compiled their controls for the silverlight 3 runtime, but before that, their SL2 controls worked fine after we ported the application to SL3. We didn't need to rewrite any code or anything at all.

But to leverage the benefits of SL3, we modularized our styles from 1 file into multiple files depending on which member was working on what part of their control.